# Parsing a text file containing multiple sections in R

Tags: r, delimiter, read.table, psse

I have a text file containing 130 tables, separated by the delimiter `' DLM'`. I tried using the package `reader` in R and defined the default delimiter as follows, but it still reads the whole file.

```
reader::reader("Path_to_file.txt", def= "\\' DLM'", one.byte = FALSE)
```

Is it possible to parse the file and read only the lines that are specific to the table name? For example, if I specify 'B2', can I read only the rows of table B2? I can't seem to get around the delimiter issue in reader. Any help is appreciated!

Sample dataset:

```
'A1',2018,10,'655033655206 1',,,81,
'A1',2019,4,'655033655206 1',,,63,
'A1',2011,1,'655034655045 1',.03486,.05829,52,


' DLM','B2',2011,1,'5BON AQUA TP',361239,161,,,0,
'B2',2001,1,'5BON AQUA TN',361240,161,22.7,4.97,0,
'B2',2002,1,'5CON FIRE TN',363240,161,22.7,4.97,0,


' DLM','C1','CGDF09',
'C1','W XYZ',
'C1','A BCD',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try removing delimiter and then check which line starts with `'B2'` ?
You can use this function from `stringi` package:

```
stri_startswith_fixed(c("A1,1,2,3","B2,3,4,5","C2,3,,5"), "B2")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I was able to parse the table based on the string match. The header for each table has to be obtained in a slightly different way, as it is in the same line as the delimiter ' DLM'.

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can accept and upvote it. :)